# JPanel only updates after the for loop is finished

Tags: java, swing

I was making a sorting visualizer and everything worked fine until I tried implementing the sort function on a button onClick. The issue is that when the sort function is called from a button, the screen doesn't refresh until the for loop is finished (normally, the sort function works perfectly).

MAIN:

```
 public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
            Test test = new Test();
        }
    }
```

TEST CLASS:

```
public class Test implements ActionListener {
    public static int WIN_WIDTH = 1500;
    public static int WIN_HEIGHT = 750;

    JButton shuffleButton;
    JButton bubbleSort;
    JFrame window;
    SortArray sortArray;

    public Test() throws InterruptedException {

        shuffleButton = new JButton();
        shuffleButton.setBounds(WIN_WIDTH + 10, 0, 160, 100);
        shuffleButton.setText("Shuffle!");

        bubbleSort = new JButton();
        bubbleSort.setBounds(WIN_WIDTH + 10, 200, 160, 100);
        bubbleSort.setText("Bubble sort!");


        window = new JFrame("Sort Visualizer");
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setSize(WIN_WIDTH + 200, WIN_HEIGHT);
        window.setVisible(true);

        sortArray = new SortArray();
        window.add(shuffleButton);
        window.add(bubbleSort);
        window.add(sortArray);

        sortArray.repaint();
        sortArray.bubble_sort();

        shuffleButton.addActionListener(this);
        bubbleSort.addActionListener(this);
        
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == shuffleButton){
            sortArray.shuffleArray();
        }else if(e.getSource() == bubbleSort){
            try {
                sortArray.bubble_sort();
            } catch (InterruptedException interruptedException) {
                interruptedException.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

SORT ARRAY CLASS:

```
 public class SortArray extends JPanel {
    private static int NM_NM = WIN_WIDTH;
    public static int BAR_WIDTH = WIN_WIDTH / NM_NM;
    private int[] array;

public SortArray() throws InterruptedException {
   shuffleArray();
}

public void shuffleArray(){
    Random rng = new Random();
    array = new int[NM_NM];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        repaint();
        array[i] = rng.nextInt(WIN_HEIGHT);
    }
}

public void bubble_sort() throws InterruptedException {
    SwingWorker<Void, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            //bubble sort
            System.out.println("sorting...");
            Boolean not_sorted = true;
            while (not_sorted) {
                TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS.sleep(1);
                not_sorted = false;
                for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
                    if (array[i] > array[i - 1]) {
                        int temp = array[i];
                        array[i] = array[i-1];
                        array[i-1] = temp;
                        not_sorted = true;
                        repaint();
                    }
                }
                if (!not_sorted) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
    worker.execute();
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D graphics2D = (Graphics2D) g;
    super.paintComponent(graphics2D);
    for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
        graphics2D.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        graphics2D.fillRect(j * BAR_WIDTH, 0, BAR_WIDTH, array[j]);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: A class mate asked the same question yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62668532/repaint-method-not-calling-paintcomponent

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it, basically all I did was surround all the commands inside the bubbleSort() function with a SwingWorker and then executed it. (This creates a background thread). I edited the code to the right one.

Comment: This is not the proper solution. Yes, the SwingWorker is a good start, but you need to "publish" the current state of the array so it can be painted. You don't want to have the sorting Thread update the array while you are trying to paint the array. Follow the link provided and read the comments to better understand the complete solution.