# QuickSort visualisation via java swing

Tags: java, swing, sorting, visualization

I wanted to make some kind of sorting algorithms visualisation is java swing but I am stuck on  quicksort since I need to stop the partition loop every iteration so the array can redraw. That's how I wanted to do it but without any success

```
 public int partition(int lowIndex, int highIndex,int i)
    {
        int pivot = highIndex;

        for(int j=lowIndex; j<highIndex; j++)
        {
            if(isBigger(j,pivot))
            {
                i++;
                swap(i,j);
                return i;
            }
        }
         swap(i+1,pivot);

        return i+1;
    }
```

Didn't find any good solution to keep track on i as well. I'm just clueless

Comment: Q: So what is it you want to "visualize"?  The elements in your array, and how they change each step in the sorting process?  Do you want to see the whole array, and "animate" when an element "swaps"?

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I want to do, and as far as I tried  simply redrawing after swapping 2 elements doesn't work

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62668532/repaint-method-not-calling-paintcomponent for the approach you need to follow.

Comment: I was doing similiar thing, but with Timer object. I have no clue how to "save" these arrays every swap so process can draw them

Comment: *I have no clue how to "save" these arrays* - I didn't use the word "save" anywhere in the other answer. I used the word "publish" because that is how the SwingWorker allows you to update the frame with intermediate results. So, you create a new Array. Copy the items from the old to the new Array. Then you publish the new Array.

Comment: I succeed doing it, my main problem was that I wanted to have quicksort in separate class and had problems with handling publish(). After some refactoring I did it. Thank you very much for help

Answer (score 1):

Google for "Java swing visualize sorting algorithms" and you'll find many hits.

For example:

[Code Review: sorting algorithm visualization program](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/238285/this-is-a-sorting-algorithm-visualization-program)

Key points:

- You need to modify your "sort" code to trigger some kind of "event" at each step (e.g. every time you swap elements):

  EXAMPLE:

  ```
  public class BubbleSort implements SortingAlgorithm {
    ...
    @Override
    public void doSort(int[] nums) {
      ...
      SortingAlgorithm.setCurrentBar(j+1);
      SortingAlgorithm.sleepFor(delay);
  ```
- The "event handler" will redraw the array (or, more accurately, request the Event Dispatcher thread (EDT) to repaint).
- Consequently, the event handler needs to "know about" the array, and the current index

  EXAMPLE:

  ```
  public abstract interface SortingAlgorithm {
    ...
    public abstract void doSort(int[] nums);

    public abstract void changeDelay(int delay);

    public static void setCurrentBar(int currentBarIndex) {
      PaintSurface.currentBarIndex = currentBarIndex;
    }
    ...
  ```
- There also needs to be some kind of "delay" between each step
- This example uses [SwingUtilities.invokeLater()](https://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/invokelater.shtml).  The example [camickr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62668532/repaint-method-not-calling-paintcomponent) suggests SwingWorker.

I hope that gives you a few ideas, and points you in the right direction!

Comment: ye, I realised it thanks to other people. My source code was the biggest problem. After some refactoring I made it. Thanks anyway

Comment: Feel free to "upvote" my response if you found it helpful. More importantly, please update your question briefly describing how you resolved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling partition from other class I implemented partition() and sort() methods in an anonymous SwingWorker class and after every swap in partition() method I called publish(array). Uploading source code if anyone would like to see how I solved this problem or would need help himself. Any feedback is really appreciate since it's my first "bigger" project

```
 private  void startThread()
    {
            SwingWorker sw1 = new SwingWorker()  {
                public int partition(int lowIndex, int highIndex) {
                    int pivot = highIndex;
                    int i = lowIndex - 1;
                    for (int j = lowIndex; j < highIndex; j++) {
                        if (sorter.isBigger(pivot, j)) {

                            i++;
                            sorter.swap(i, j);
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(100);
                            }
                            catch(Exception e)
                            {
                                // not implemented yet
                            }
                            publish(sorter.getArray());
                        }

                    }
                    sorter.swap(i+1,pivot);
                    publish(sorter.getArray());
                    return i+1;
                }
                public void sort(int lowIndex, int highIndex)
                {

                    if(lowIndex < highIndex)
                    {
                        int i = partition(lowIndex,highIndex);
                        try{
                           sort(lowIndex,i-1) ;
                        }
                        finally {
                            sort(i+1, highIndex);
                        }

                    }
                }
                @Override
                protected int[] doInBackground() throws Exception {
                    sorter.setArray(drafter.getArray());
                    while (!sorter.isArraySorted()) {
                        //Thread.sleep(10);
                        sort(0,sorter.getLength()-1);

                        }


                    return sorter.getArray();
                }
                protected void process(List chunks)
                {
                    int[] val = (int[]) chunks.get(chunks.size()-1);
                    drafter.ChangeArray(val);
                    //drafter.repaint();

                }

                };
            sw1.execute();

    }
```