# Java Swing removeAll() not removing

Tags: java, swing

I'm making a sorting visualizer, is my first time working with Java GUI, so I'm struggling a bit.

At this moment, everything is working fine, but every time the `arraylist` updates, I want to clear up the screen and create again the rectangles. The `repaint()` method is working, but `removeAll()` isn't.

I tried with `validate()`, `revalidate()`, `updateUI()`, and nothing is working for me.

**GUI Code**

```
public class Window extends JFrame{
    private ArrayList<Integer> nums;

    private static final int WIDTH = 500;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 400;

    // Constructor
    public Window(ArrayList<Integer> nums){
        this.nums = nums;

        setSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
        setTitle("Sorting Visualizer");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    // Update method
    public void Draw(ArrayList<Integer> newNums){
        nums = newNums;
        removeAll();
        repaint();
    }

    // Paint method
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        //g.clearRect(0, 0, (int)getSize().getWidth(), (int)getSize().getHeight()); // shitty clear

        int width = WIDTH / nums.size();

        for(int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++){
            int height = (HEIGHT / nums.size()) * (nums.get(i));

            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.drawRect(i * width, HEIGHT - height, width, height);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm creating the Window and calling `Draw()` inside my sorting method, so it will update in each `for` iteration.

**Sort class**

```
public class Sort {
    // GUI instance
    Window w;

    // Constructor
    public Sort(ArrayList<Integer> nums){
        w = new Window(nums);
    }

    //Sorting algorithm
    public ArrayList<Integer> bubbleSort(ArrayList<Integer> nums){

        boolean isSorted = false;

        while(!isSorted){
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException ex)
            {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < nums.size() - 1; i++){
                if(nums.get(i) > nums.get(i + 1)){
                    int temp = nums.get(i);
                    nums.set(i, nums.get(i+1));
                    nums.set(i + 1, temp);
                }
                // Update GUI
                w.Draw(nums);
            }

            isSorted = isSorted(nums);
        }

        return nums;
    }

    // Private classes
    // Check if ArrayList is sorted
    private boolean isSorted(ArrayList<Integer> nums){
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.size() - 1; i++){
            if(nums.get(i) > nums.get(i + 1)){
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should take a look at Custom Painting in Swing for the full info on how to do this properly.  You have more than a few mistakes.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html

Comment: `removeAll()` is to remove all components you have added to your window. You haven't add any Swing/AWT components to your window to remove.

Comment: Right, because it's custom painting here.  Well spotted.  So then the call to `repaint()` should be all the OP needs?

Comment: Don't override paint() in a JFrame, especially when you don't invoke super.paint(...). You will lose default Swing functionality such as double buffering. Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63509913/java-swing-actionperformed-skips-visualization#comment112304495_63509913 for another suggestion on this topic to use a `SwingWorker` for the animation. It is important that you read the section on `Concurrency` .

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain better what "isn't working?"  All I did was uncomment your `clearRect()` and it seems to work OK.

I think what might be going on is the call the `Tread.sleep()` blocks the GUI thread.  At first I ran the code on the GUI thread, but with the `Thread.sleep()` it just blocked most of the time.  So I ran it on the main thread and it worked.  You'll have some extra work to do to get two threads communicating properly so you can run the window code on the GUI thread.

```
public class CustomPainting {
   
   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList( Arrays.asList( 4,3,2,1 ) );
      new Sort( list ).bubbleSort( list );
//      SwingUtilities.invokeLater( CustomPainting::start );
   }

   private static void start() {
   }

}

class Window extends JFrame {

   private ArrayList<Integer> nums;

   private static final int WIDTH = 500;
   private static final int HEIGHT = 400;

   // Constructor
   public Window( ArrayList<Integer> nums ) {
      this.nums = nums;

      setSize( WIDTH, HEIGHT );
      setTitle( "Sorting Visualizer" );
      setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

      setVisible( true );
   }

   // Update method
   public void Draw( ArrayList<Integer> newNums ) {
      nums = newNums;
//      removeAll();
      repaint();
   }

   // Paint method
   public void paint( Graphics g ) {
      g.clearRect(0, 0, (int)getSize().getWidth(), (int)getSize().getHeight()); // shitty clear

      int width = WIDTH / nums.size();

      for( int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++ ) {
         int height = (HEIGHT / nums.size()) * (nums.get( i ));

         g.setColor( Color.BLUE );
         g.drawRect( i * width, HEIGHT - height, width, height );
      }
   }
}
 class Sort {
    // GUI instance
    Window w;

    // Constructor
    public Sort(ArrayList<Integer> nums){
        w = new Window(nums);
    }

    //Sorting algorithm
    public ArrayList<Integer> bubbleSort(ArrayList<Integer> nums){

        boolean isSorted = false;

        while(!isSorted){
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(400);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException ex)
            {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < nums.size() - 1; i++){
                if(nums.get(i) > nums.get(i + 1)){
                    int temp = nums.get(i);
                    nums.set(i, nums.get(i+1));
                    nums.set(i + 1, temp);
                }
                // Update GUI
                w.Draw(nums);
                System.err.println( nums );
            }

            isSorted = isSorted(nums);
        }

        return nums;
    }

    // Private classes
    // Check if ArrayList is sorted
    private boolean isSorted(ArrayList<Integer> nums){
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.size() - 1; i++){
            if(nums.get(i) > nums.get(i + 1)){
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```